# How can I detect a user is using speech-to-text?

Tags: android, ios, xamarin.forms, speech-to-text, hipaa

Is there any way I can detect when a user is using their phone's Speech-To-Text feature with Xamarin?

The application I'm working on needs to be HIPAA compliant and the Speech-To-Text APIs are not HIPAA compliant. I would like to find a way to prevent the user from using these features. I'm willing to reject Speech-To-Text input, disable the ability to use these features, or at minimum detect when Speech-To-Text is used.

Any and all help is appreciated.

Comment: Can you explain a little further why is an API (= a set of interface declarations) not HIPAA compliant? One solution could be to block the microphone while the user is in your app, if this is the issue here...

Comment: The text to speech APIs don't encrypt the patient information. I would block the microphone if I could figure out how.

Answer (score 1):

Only a single app can use the microphone at a time (although this might change in the future). So to block the microphone or to find out if another app has done it, you could simply construct an [AudioRecord](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/AudioRecord) (and possibly call some methods on it).

Note that some speech-to-text implementations might meet the privacy requirements by doing on-device speech recognition or use a server in the local network. So blocking these would be unfair and not what the user would expect.